# Spill to disk and shuffle write spark

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, shuffle

I'm getting confused about `spill to disk` and `shuffle write`. Using the default Sort shuffle manager, we use an `appendOnlyMap` for aggregating and combine partition records, right? Then when execution memory fill up, we start sorting map, spilling it to disk and then clean up the map for the next spill(if occur), my questions are :

- What is the difference between spill to disk and shuffle write? They consist basically in creating file on local file system and also record.
- Admit are different, so Spill records are sorted because the are passed through the map, instead shuffle write records no because they don't pass from the map.
- I have the idea that the total size of the spilled file, should be equal to the size of the Shuffle write, maybe I'm missing something, please help to understand that phase.

Thanks.

Giorgio

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`spill to disk` and `shuffle write` are two different things

`spill to disk` - *Data move from Host RAM to Host Disk* - is used when there is no enough RAM on your machine, and it place part of its RAM into disk

http://spark.apache.org/faq.html

**Does my data need to fit in memory to use Spark?**

> No. Spark's operators spill data to disk if it does not fit in memory,
>   allowing it to run well on any sized data. Likewise, cached datasets
>   that do not fit in memory are either spilled to disk or recomputed on
>   the fly when needed, as determined by the RDD's storage level.

`shuffle write` - *Data move from Executor(s) to another Executor(s)* - is used when data needs to move between executors (e.g. due to JOIN, groupBy, etc)

more data can be found here:

- https://0x0fff.com/spark-architecture-shuffle/
- http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/05/working-with-apache-spark-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-the-shuffle/

An edge case example which might help clearing this issue:

- You have 10 executors
- Each executor with 100GB RAM
- Data size is 1280MB, and is partitioned into 10 partitions
- Each executor holds 128MB of data.

Assuming that the data holds one key, Performing groupByKey, will bring all the data into one partition. `Shuffle size` will be 9*128MB (9 executors will transfer their data into the last executor), and there won't be any `spill to disk` as the executor has 100GB of RAM and only 1GB of data

Regarding [AppendOnlyMap](https://searchcode.com/file/95719774/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/collection/AppendOnlyMap.scala) :

> As written in the `AppendOnlyMap` code (see above) - this function is
>   a low level implementation of a simple open hash table optimized for
>   the append-only use case, where keys are never removed, but the value
>   for each key may be changed.

The fact that two different modules uses the same low-level function doesn't mean that those functions are related in hi-level.

Comment: But if spill doesn't occur, it means that aggregated records don't pass from the appendOnlyMap? So that they will be unsorted?

Comment: If spill-to-disk doesn't occur, it means that the executor can hold the entire data in RAM (see edge case example in my answer)

Comment: So appendOnlyMap being used just for spill? Spilled files contains records to be shuffled later or are just objects used for the elaboration that can't stay in RAM?  I still continue to think that are related because I think that every records must pass from the appendOnlyMap, please clarify It, thanks

Comment: My doubt came maybe from the sort shuffle manager where looking at Image post you link, each map task has his appendOnlyMap.

Comment: @Giorgio - I've added a note regarding `AppendOnlyMap`