# PySpark Unable to Spill on DataFrame Write

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am processing a large-ish dataset using PySpark 2.4.4 which comes with Hadoop built-in. The dataset is split into multiple compressed CSV files and I am attempting to report aggregate counts of various columns using PySpark's DataFrames. PySpark is handling everything beautifully until I ask it to write the DataFrame to the disk using

```py
df.write.csv("out.csv")
```

Which results in the following warning flooding the terminal

```
WARN RowBasedKeyValueBatch: Calling spill() on RowBasedKeyValueBatch. Will not spill but return 0.
```

I tried increasing the size of the executor's memory using the `spark.executor.memory` property; however, the error persisted. I don't know if it is okay to ignore this warning or if I need to change something before trusting the result of the reports.

There are two answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46907447/meaning-of-apache-spark-warning-calling-spill-on-rowbasedkeyvaluebatch) to a similar question, but I am not satisfied with their depth. The answer by Fredz0r simply references [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41661849/spill-to-disk-and-shuffle-write-spark) explaining the difference between spill and shuffle, but does not seem to address the `...Will not spill...` portion of the message. The remaining answer is worded as if this is a serious warning, but gives no suggestions for how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I really think that the answers you point to already cover almost everything.

Some extra tips that I can think of, giving that you mention that you are doing some grouping are:

- Maybe you have some data skew that causes one (or some) of the partitions to be very big, and hence the executor/s holding these partitions need even more memorty than you have already allocated
- If you are writting to the driver local disk instead of some distributed filesystem (Ex. HDFS), you will be collecting all the results to the driver and hence you will need to raise the driver memory instead of the executors memory.

Comment: The answers describe what spill is, but they don't explain how to make the warning go away. I don't have a distributed filesystem, but I can't find the spark property to increase driver memory. What property do I set for that?

Comment: You can use `spark.driver.memory`